# iOS swift: since 11.2 strange borders on some UiViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, border

Since I've updated to iOS 11.2 on my iPhone 8 plus I see strange borders on some views. Not all, but just some.

I've tried to set the border color to clear, the border size to 0, but still the border are there.

If I try to take a screenshot the picture doesn't show the borders.
If I play the app from an other iOS version or from simulator there aren't any border.

Did some one have the same bug? Do you know a fix?

Comment: debug version, are you sure about it? How could I solve it?

Comment: did what you said, still I see the problem.. But thank you

Comment: Might be connected to this issue, where reason is missing launch screen for specified resolution
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2018